# Solution to problem 5.3 Book Quantum Computation and Quantum Information Nielsen Chuang regarding Kitaev's algorithm

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang

Problem 5.3: (Kitaev’s algorithm) Consider the quantum circuit
[image: Kitaev's algorithm]

where |u> is an eigenstate of U with eigenvalue $e ^ {2 \pi i \phi} $. Show that the top qubit is measured to be 0 with probability $p = cos^{2}(\pi \phi)$. Since the state |u> is unaffected by the circuit it may be reused; if U can be replaced by $U ^{k}$, where k is an
arbitrary integer under your control, show that by repeating this circuit and
increasing k appropriately, you can efficiently obtain as many bits of p as desired,
and thus, of $ \phi $. This is an alternative to the phase estimation algorithm.

Could you kindly show

1. How the top qubit is 0 with probability $p = cos^{2}(\pi \phi)$
2. The algorithm/procedure for replacing U by $U ^{k}$, where k is an arbitrary integer under your control , repeating this circuit and what are the appropriate values for k, and how to efficiently obtain as many bits of p as desired, and thus, of $ \phi $.

The purpose for asking this question is that I wish to arrive at a iterative Quantum Phase Estimation algorithm for computing each bit in the phase, bit by bit.

I am continuing the answers to @DaftWullie here since the system is warning me not to use comments.

To answer to your latest post, I can use $U^{2}$ operator to calculate whether $ \phi $ is 0 or $ \pi/4 $.

Thank you Dani007. Your post answers the first part of my question. It would be great if someone could answer the second question as well.

Comment: What have you tried? Specifically, have you tried to find the output of the circuit and, if so, what did you get?

Comment: I calculated the answer to the first question. The first step is the Hadamard operator on the state |0> with output (|0> + |1>)/sqrt(2). The next step is Controlled-U which after substituting the phase-kickback $e^{2 \pi \phi}$ becomes  $1/ \sqrt{(2)} (|0> + e^{2 \pi \phi}|1>)|u>$ and finally applying Hadamard transform becomes (1/ 2) ((|0> + |1>) + e^{2 \pi \phi}(|0> - |1>))|u>$ which on simplifying becomes (1/ 2) ((|0>(1 + e^{2 \pi \phi}) + |1>) (1 - e^{2 \pi \phi}|u>$.

Comment: You're missing some factors of $i$ from the exponents. But yes, this is the answer. This is the same as $(\cos(\pi\phi)|0\rangle+i\sin(\pi\phi)|1\rangle)|u\rangle$ (up toa global phase). So, what's the probability of getting answer 0 if you measure the first qubit?

Comment: the probability is $cos ^2 {(\Pi \Phi)}$. Thank you. But I don't know the answer to the second question.

Comment: Yup, so that's what you were after for question 1. Question 2: $|u\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $U^k$ with what eigenvalue?

Comment: Now you probably want to answer a sequence of 3 questions. (i) If I promise you that $\phi=0$ or $\phi=1/2$, how would you distinguish which it is with a single run of your original circuit? (ii) If I promise you that $\phi=0$ or $\phi=1/4$, how would you modify your circuit to tell in a single run, which it is? (iii) if $\phi=0,1/4,1/2,3/4$, how would you tell which it is?

Comment: The eigenvalue is $e^{2 \pi i k \phi}$

Comment: Answer to Q1. I would calculate the probability p of the qubit being |0>. If $\phi = 0$, then $p = cos^{2}{0} = 1$. If $\phi = 1/2$, then $p = cos^{2}(\pi / 2) = 0$. I don't know the answer to Questions 2 and 3 in your post.

Comment: Well, how can you convert question 2 into question 1?

Comment: I could probably repeat answer to Question 1 with the phase being $2 \phi$.

Comment: And what operation has an eigenvalue $e^{2\pi i (2\phi)}$?

Comment: I could use operator $U^{2}$ |u> to distinguish between $ \phi  = 0$ and $\phi = 1/4 $

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have an ancilla qubit in a circuit, you can reduce the problem into a 2-dimensional problem by thinking of the circuit in terms of blocking encodings:

$$H \otimes I^n =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} I^n & I^n \\
I^n & -I^n \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

and the controlled operation on $U$ can be written as:

$$\begin{bmatrix} I^n & 0 \\
0 & U \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Then the circuit becomes:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} I^n & I^n \\
I^n & -I^n \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} I^n & 0 \\
0 & U \\ \end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} I^n & I^n \\
I^n & -I^n \\ \end{bmatrix} \\= \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} I^n + U & I^n - U \\
I^n - U & I^n + U \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

We can then represent the incoming state as:

$$\vert 0 \rangle\vert u \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} \vert u\rangle \\
0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore, the state of the system before the measurement can be represented as:

$$\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} I^n + U & I^n - U \\
I^n - U & I^n + U \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \vert u\rangle \\
0 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} (I^n + U)\vert u\rangle \\
(I^n - U)\vert u\rangle \\ \end{bmatrix}\\
= \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} (1 + e^{i2\pi\phi})\vert u\rangle\\
(1 - e^{i2\pi\phi})\vert u\rangle \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Since $\vert u \rangle$ must have norm 1, then the probability of measuring the ancilla to be 0 is:

$$\frac{1}{4}\vert\vert 1 + e^{i2\pi\phi}\vert\vert^2 = \frac{1}{4}((1+ cos(2\pi\phi))^2 + sin(2\pi\phi)^2)\\
= \frac{1}{4}(1+ 2cos(2\pi\phi) + cos(2\pi\phi)^2 + sin(2\pi\phi)^2)\\
= \frac{1}{2}(1+ cos(2\pi\phi))$$

Now $cos(2\pi\phi) = cos(\pi\phi)^2 - sin(\pi\phi)^2$. So we get:

$$\frac{1}{2}(1+ cos(2\pi\phi)) =  \frac{1}{2}(cos(\pi\phi)^2 + sin(\pi\phi)^2 + cos(\pi\phi)^2 - sin(\pi\phi)^2)\\
= cos(\pi\phi)^2$$

Now replacing $U$ with $U^k$ the same logic gives us $cos(k\pi\phi)^2$ which has a period of $\frac{1}{k}$ which doesn't divide $2\pi$ (period of $\phi$), it also has a peak at 1. So while $cos(\pi\phi)^2 = x$  and $cos(k\pi\phi)^2 = y$ each have a number of possible solutions, $\phi$ must be in the intersection of the 2 sets of solutions, so you can eliminate a whole lot of them by choosing $k$ cleverly.

Comment: Thank you Dani007. Your post answers the first part of my question. It would be great if someone could answer the second question as well.